# After requestAuthorization on first load the rest of viewDidLoad isn't executed and the next line jumps to the delegate functions (swift 3)

Tags: swift, google-maps, core-location, cllocationmanager

My app seems to work fine on each use except the first one.
I ask for user authorization and I have the appropriate keys in the plist but the rest of viewDidLoad after the lines requesting authorization don't execute. I have attached the breakpoints below and breakpoint 2 isn't hit on the first time the app is used.

I'm pretty sure after authorization is given it just jumps to the func locationManager in the extension.

I could wait till the very end to ask for authorization until everything else is set but not sure if this is the best, or only way, out.

Thanks,

```
 class MapController: UIViewController, GMSMapViewDelegate {

    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var currentLocation: CLLocation?  

    @IBOutlet var mapView: GMSMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()

        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
--------------------------> breakpoint 1
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
-------------------------> breakpoint 2
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.distanceFilter = 50
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        locationManager.delegate = self

        guard let lat = locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude else {return}
        guard let lng = locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude else {return}

        mapView.settings.compassButton = true
        mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
        mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true

        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: lat, longitude: lng, zoom: 1)            
        mapView.camera = camera            
        mapView.delegate = self
          getData()
    }

    extension MapController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

        func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

            guard let location: CLLocation = locations.last else {return}     
            let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude, zoom: 1)

            mapView.animate(to: camera)    
        }
}
```

Comment: You might want to see the comments on the answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you request authorisation to two different things? If you request and get always authorisation, you don't need to request when in use authorisation, since this is only a subset of always authorisation.

Also, these are both asynchronous functions, so you cannot execute location based code right after them, since if you don't have authorisation yet, the code right after `requestAuthorization()` will be executed before you actually got authorisation and hence the functions won't be called, since you don't have authorisation yet.

You have to check the authorisation status before calling any location related code, such as `locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()` and only execute the location related code if the status is authorised. If it is not authorised, you have to implement `CLLocationManagerDelegate`'s `locationManager(_:didChangeAuthorization:)` function and call the location related call inside that function after checking that the result of the change is an authorised status.

Comment: That's what I don't quite get. If request authorization is async then why isn't the rest of viewDidLoad executing? Also if it's async then shouldn't the next line location.startUpdatingLocation() execute anywawy? And can you explain why in my example why the locationManager delegate didUpdateLocations was called anyway even though I didn't have startUpdatingLocations()? Finally, if there is a delegate function didChangeAuthorization why isn't all the code in that function waiting for a change in authorization? Thanks.

Comment: As I said, it isn't executing, because you cannot call location based functions until the authorisation status is defined. If `startUpdatingLocations` never gets called, then the delegate function cannot be called, so `startUpdatingLocations` must be called in your code if the delegate is called. `didChangeAuthorization` is only relevant the first time your app is started or if the user changes the authorisation status in settings, otherwise this function won't be called again.

Comment: my setup is something like `manager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()` do you mean until I don't click on the 'Allow'...I won't be getting any updates but after clicking I would get updates OR you mean because `startUpdatingLocation` gets evaluated immediately at a time where we haven't yet clicked on the allow yet it would silently fail completely  ?

Comment: Thanks for you response David. But I have a question about your initial response where you say the authorisation functions are asynchronous. I thought if they were asynchronous while requestAuthorisation is doing its thing in the background - either allow or not - everything else in viewDidLoad should continue to get executed eg. the mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true and the function at the end getData(). But that's not what happens. getData is never reached during the app's first run. In Google's ios docs they talk about having the mapView setup in loadView...do you do that?

Comment: @Mike yes, in general execution continues while an async request is executed on another thread. However, as I have stated this before several times: this is a special case, because some of the other functions actually depend on the result of the async authorisation function and if the authorisation did not happen, they won't throw an error, they just don't get executed at all. `mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true` needs location authorisation, so it cannot be executed until authorisation happens, hence it is not even called on the first run of your app.

Comment: @Honey if you write `requestAuthorization` and `startUpdatingLocations` in subsequent lines, the second line wouldn't even get called if the authorisation status is not authorised. And yes, you won't receive any errors, the function just won't get called.

Comment: The reason I asked this was because I had a similar issue and did a small test now to be sure. I waited till I got the Allow popup. Once the popup came, I waited another 2 minutes and then clicked on the allow. After that I was getting callbacks for my location updates. Doesn't this invalidate what you have said?

Comment: Thanks David. That makes sense. One final ques. When I authorise locations on my iphone startUpdateLocations is run and then the program leaves viewDidLoad at this point and the delegate func locationManager(didUpdateLocations) is called. Which is good but it means the mapView setup stuff eg. mapView.compassButton, mapView.isLocationEnabled..doesn't happen in viewDidLoad. I wasn't sure I should put the mapView code in the func locationManager(didUpdateLocations) because I really only need some of that mapView stuff to be called just the once. I was wondering how you go about it. Thanks.

Comment: @Honey I haven't tested it recently, so if you run your tests recently, you might be right, I will have to test this behaviour again. However, when running the tests, one has to make sure, `viewDidLoad` isn't called again and it is the system that calls `startUpdatingLocations` after the location authorisation happened.

Comment: @Mike what you should do is to check if the status is authorizated and act accordingly. If it is authorised, call the map view related functions inside viewDidLoad. If it is not authorised, call the functions from inside `didChangeAuthorizationStatus`. In both cases, the setup will only happen once.

Comment: Thanks for the advice

Comment: 1. "one has to make sure, viewDidLoad isn't called again " What do you mean by that?  2. " it is the system that calls startUpdatingLocations after the location authorisation happened" I removed `locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()` and only kept `requestAlwaysAuthorization` line...waiting to see if it runs afterwards. It didn't! Meaning the system doesn't seem to call it. But what's funny was that I placed `startUpdatingLocations` before requesting and it still worked!!!! Different levels of requests made no difference for what I'm saying. (FYI I deleted the app each time I ran my test)

Comment: 1. I mean did you just leave your app running with the authorisation request opened? 2. So it actually seems if you call `startUpdatingLocations`, it is getting called as soon as the authorisation happens regardless of where you put that in code, interesting.

Comment: my locationmanager was instantiated completely in a lazy var. But yest I just left the app running with the authorization request opened